# ssh to termux server disconnects after X seconds

Tags: termux

I upgraded `termux` recently.

When I do:

```
ssh phone
```

it disconnects after 44 seconds. It disconnects even if there is activity in the session (eg. `ping google.com`).

If I am active in `termux` using the phone, then `ssh` does not disconnect. So it seems Android is killing the `ssh` connection. `tcpdump` confirms that and shows a reset packet is sent from the phone killing the connection:

```
13:30:37.093254 IP 192.168.1.122.2222 > 192.168.1.129.41938: Flags [R.], seq 4542, ack 5622, win 396, options [nop,nop,TS val 3374991 ecr 3768615485], length 0
```

Before upgrading `termux` this did not happen. So something happened during the upgrade that caused this to happen.

I have tried both to click `acquire wakelock` and `release wakelock`. Neither helped.

I have tried both to click `allow` and `don't allow` in Battery Optimization for Termux. Neither helped.

As a workaround I can connect USB. Then Android does not disconnect the `ssh`-connection. This makes me think the disconnection is deliberate and related to power saving.

How can I make Android not kill the `ssh` connection?

Comment: Android isn't killing `ssh` but Termux app because it doesn't have a background service running. You  need to keep Termux in foreground. Or disable Battery Optimization for Termux and *Acquire wakelock*. When phone is charging over USB, Battery Optimization isn't in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @IrfanLatif I looked at battery options again.

And my phone was in Power Saving mode. When I disabled that, everything worked - whether Termux is running in the foreground or not.

So the problem was not related to the upgrade of Termux.